# Saving Warnings to a variable in powershell

Tags: variables, powershell, scripting, warnings

So what I'm trying to do is this

```
 $corruptAccounts = Get-Mailbox | select-string -pattern WARNING
```

The intent is to fill the variable `$corruptAccounts` with the warnings from `Get-Mailbox`. What actually happens is it processes the `Get-Mailbox` command, displaying the warnings, and puts nothing into the variable.

I'm new to powershell so I'm still trying to learn some of the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-MailBox -WarningVariable wv
$wv
```

`-WarningVariable` is a common parameter available for all advanced functions and binary cmdlets.

Here is a generic example:

```
Function TestWarning {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (

    )

    Write-Warning "This is a warning"
}

PS C:\> TestWarning -WarningVariable wv
WARNING: This is a warning

PS C:\> $wv
This is a warning
```

Comment: I tried Get-Mailbox with the -WarningVariable and it did not put anything into the variable. I tried with wv and $wv

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$var = @();
Get-Mailbox -WarningVariable +var -ResultSize unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

$buf = Get-Mailbox 2>&1 | Out-String

Will add warnings to $buf at front